# Webcam pool using Flash Media Server

Tags: flash, media, flash-media-server

I have an application where users can log in and connect to the Flash media server. Once they have been connected, anyone can view their webcam.

For example, lets say Bob and Sally log on to the website and their cameras are now being streamed. Bob can view Sally's webcam stream at http://www.example.com?cam=sally and Sally can view Bob's webcam stream at http://www.example.com?cam=bob

Comment: Haven't done this just yet, but look into using netstream and the netstreams attachCamera-function :)

Comment: @Noman Ur Rehman You say, that their cameras are now being streamed? Then how are they going to see each other? And I cannot understand, what are you asking for? What's your problem? Connecting to FMS? Streaming video? Playing video? Could you give some more details? Thanks

Comment: What I am trying to ask is I already know how to stream a user's webcam to the media server and play with it, say record an flv file. I want to know how is this possible that you could make multiple cameras of different user's accessible to eachother ? I want to make Bob and Sally connect to my media server and then I want them both to be able to see eachother's webcam output like Bob and see Sally on the webcam and vice versa. Similarly, the number of users will not be limited to 2.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to broadcast webcam stream to FMS:

```
    var nc : NetConnection = new NetConnection( );
        nc.client = this;
        nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, statusHandler );
        nc.connect( "rtmp://your-fms-server-url/your-application" );

    var cam : Camera = Camera.getCamera( );
        cam.setMode( 640, 480, 20 );

    var ns : NetStream;

    function statusHandler ( eventOBJ : NetStatusEvent )
    {
        if ( eventOBJ.info.code == "NetConnection.Connect.Success" )
        {
            ns = new NetStream( nc );
            ns.attachCamera( cam );
            ns.publish( "your-stream-name" );
        }
    };
```

The receiver is simliar, except a few lines:

```
    // to the declaration section:
    var video : Video = new Video( );

    // code in the statusHandler method:
    if ( eventOBJ.info.code == "NetConnection.Connect.Success" )
    {
        ns = new NetStream( nc );
        ns.play( "your-stream-name", -1 );
        video.attachNetStream( ns );    
        addChild( video );
    }
```

And you simply pass the name of the desired stream in flashvars.
For example if you use this url: www.yourdomain.com/chat.php?cam=Sally, in this case pass the cam parameter to the SWF client, and use in the following form:

```
    ns.play( this.loaderInfo.parameters.cam , -1 );
```